# Select the most popular song based on other column values

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a temporary table that is generated on top of other tables. Now I have a problem to get the top-ranked(count) song based on each country. Five is the highest rank in this case, then four, three...

```
Country     Song    count

=================================
Japan       s006     5
USA         s004     5
Italy       sx32     5
Holland     tm31     5
Japan       st00     4
Italy       tm31     4
Japan       tm31     4
Holland     ab45     4
USA         mn55     3
USA         5607     3
Holland     sx32     3
Italy       ab45     2
USA         i202     1
Holland     s004     1
Japan       sx32     1
Holland     s004     1


Expect output:

Country     Song    

====================
Japan       s006     
USA         s004     
Italy       sx32     
Holland     tm31
```

Then how can I get the top II rank e.g of each country?

Output 2:

```
Country     Song    

====================
Japan       s006  
Japan       st00   
USA         s004 
USA         mn55 (note 5607 has the same rank, maybe just ignore?)
Italy       sx32     
Italy       tm31
Holland     tm31    
Holland     ab45
```

I have tried several options. The most close one was like select distinct(country), max(count). But then I don't have the code of that song show in the column. FYI, I have already used count function when I made primary query. Ant suggestions? Thanks!

Comment: I'm a little confused on what you want.  You seem to have too questions and that is a bit broad.

Comment: @GordonLinoff, if let's put in a simple way, what can I do to get the first expect output? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with row_number():

```
select t.Country, t.Song
from (
  select *,
    row_number() over (partition by Country order by count desc) rn
  from tablename
) t
where t.rn = 1
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/nRBm8JnwxB8BaYo8J5iYeV/0).
Results:

```
| country | song |
| ------- | ---- |
| Holland | tm31 |
| Italy   | sx32 |
| Japan   | s006 |
| USA     | s004 |
```

Change the condition to:

```
where t.rn <= 2
```

to get the top 2 ranked songs for each country.

Comment: thanks very much. I 'm thinking how to combine it with my another query that I used as temp table to get this table. One min, I will paste that query soon.

Comment: And further to that if USA 5607 should be included because it's the same *rank* change "row_number()" to "rank()"

Comment: @LJ01 why? The expected results in the question do not include ties.

Comment: @forpas, I tried myself to solve it. It has several tables. table 1, table 2, table 3 for example. The one I pasted here was a temporary result I have generated based on the my first effort

Comment: It's in the written requirements though, and there's a note about it in the expected results... "Now I have a problem to get the top-ranked(count) song based on each country. " & "5607 has the same rank, maybe just ignore". I thought that justified suggesting rank as well. + 1 because your answer returns the output

Comment: select tb1.country as country, 
    song, COUNT('song') AS count 
from   table1 tb1
inner join table2 tb2 on tb1.happening_id=tb2.happening_id
inner join table3 tb3 on tb1.id =tb3.id
group by tb2.country,tb2.song
order by count DESC

Comment: It is a little bit messy, I paste it in code section

Comment: @soho something like: select t.Country, t.Song
from (
  select tb1.country, tb2.song, 
    row_number() over (partition by Country order by COUNT(song) desc) rn 
  from table1 tb1 
  inner join table2 tb2 on tb1.happening_id=tb2.happening_id 
  inner join table3 tb3 on tb1.id = tb3.id 
  group by tb1.country, tb2.song
) t
where t.rn = 1

Comment: Although it is not clear for the columns in which table they belong.

Comment: @forpas many thanks, I guess I could figure out. I don't have the upvote rights yet, but I marked it as a accepted answer. Thanks again :)

Comment: @forpas, just let you know, I solved it based on your hint.Thanks!  The final solution includes two temporary tables. Based on your experience, which one is faster? Separate the complicated query into several small queries and then combine together or put many subqueries in one table?

Comment: Many subqueries? How many? Postgresql is very efficient when it comes to CTEs: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/queries-with.html If you have subqueries that do not depend on each other it's better to make a CTE for each of them and then use them just like you would use a table.

Comment: @forpas. Thanks. I will check out the link. I have been thinking that if I am working on a big data. For example two years of user data. That's why I was asking. :)